# HTML video tag is not working in android(4.2.2) webView(Chrome[62])

Tags: android, html, android-studio, android-webview

I have built a app in android in which I am trying to show 3 videos in single screen at a time.

For displaying video I am using webView of chrome(version 62).
Inside HTML I have below code

```
<video id="vid1" class="vids" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="pathTotVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

**I am using android 4.2.2**

Now problem is that when page loads, video tag is there but I don't see any video playing. Even if I provide '**contorls**' attribute inside video tag still the play button is greyed out.

Even there is no error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Video tag's attributes should be specified for strict standard implementation:

```
<video id="vid1" class="vids" width="100%" height="100%" muted loop autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
    <source src="pathTotVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Replace your current video tag with above one. Please do let me know whether its working or not.

Please add below code before proceeding to webview

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());               
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);              
webView.loadUrl("your web view path");
```

Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` as a child in your activity manifest file. It plays html5 video inside webviews without any workaround.

For example:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...It did not work. I have to manually click on play button to play the videos.

Comment: I checked your edited answer. I have already added those line in my android app... still not able to get it working. :(

Comment: I have again edited my answer.. Please go through once.

Comment: thank you...but I have added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` too

Comment: Can you please this code also to your webView 

`webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`